# Excel - If cell value matches column header, copy data to column

Tags: vba, excel

I have string data in Column A, I have number values in Column B. I also have Columns O to Z which are currently blank - these columns have headers 1, 2, 3 etc. (i.e. cell references O2=1, P2=2, Q2=3 etc.)

There is a number value in cell C1.

If C1 = matches any of the column headers (O-Z) then copy the data from Column B to the corresponding column.

Example: If C1 = 4 and cell R2 is 4, the data from Column B would populate in Column R.

How do I achieve this with VBA? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I had used formulas to begin with but then realised it wouldn't work and that VBA would allow me to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this...

```
Sub CopyDataDynamically()
Dim lr As Long, num As Long
Dim rng As Range
lr = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("O2")
num = Range("C1").Value
If num > 0 And num <= 12 Then
    Range("B2:B" & lr).Copy
    rng.Offset(0, num - 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
End If
End Sub
```

If you want to achieve this with the help of a formula, try this...

In O2

```
=IF($B2="","",IF(O$1=$C$1,$B2,""))
```

and then copy it across and down as far as there is data in column B.

Comment: Thanks sktneer. This works very well, the only problems I experienced were..

The bottom row of Column B didn't pull through to it's destination

If I can, I would like the column headers to remain as before (so not data copies over these headers (cells O2-Z2) - thanks again.

Comment: @topstuff You're welcome! Glad it worked. Please take a minute to accept the answer to mark your question as Solved. :)

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention. The data in Column B is from formulas. How would I be able to copy only the values over, as opposed to the formulas?

Comment: You're welcome! I have also added a formula solution.